# provide data for protractor test

Tags: node.js, protractor

I'm new to nodejs and working now to automatize functionnal test doing BDD with cucumber and  protractor.
For some of my steps, i need to send query to an oracle database and then use the result to make a search in the tested website.

1- I'm trying with oracleDB witch returns me the expected result that i put in a variable but this one is not available in my steps. Method sendKeys of webdriver puts "undefined"  in the input. 
2- I'm also wondering if there's not another way because it was hard to install oracledb and the next task is to have jenkins builds

here is my code:

```
 var dbQueryContract = function() {
  var oracledb  = require('oracledb');
//Database communication
oracledb.getConnection(
          {
            user          : "xxx",
            password      : "xxx",
            connectString : "xxx"
          },
          function(err, connection)
          {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err.message);
              return;
            }
            connection.execute(
              "select xxx, xxx " +
                "FROM xxxxx " +
                "where xxx is not null and rownum < 5",
                {
             resultSet: true
         },
                // bind value for :id [110],
                function(err, result)
     {
       if (err) { console.error(err.message); return; }
       console.log(result.rows[0][0]);
     });

criteria= result.rows[0][0];
// the connection is ok and i can log result.rows[0][0] i want to use for search


});
};
module.exports = new dbQueryContract();

************************************************************************************************


// Use the external Chai As Promised to deal with resolving promises in
// expectations.
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

var expect = chai.expect;
  var page1 = require('../page1.js');
  var page2 = require('../page2.js');
  var dbQueryContract = require('../dbQueryContract.js');
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;


// Chai expect().to.exist syntax makes default jshint unhappy.
// jshint expr:true

module.exports = function() {
  this.Given(/^thanx for help$/, function(next) {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
    browser.get('toto.com');
       page1.login.sendKeys('login')
        page1.password.sendKeys('P@ssword')
        page1.validateButton.click();
        browser.ignoreSynchronization=false;
        page2.searchLink.click();
        browser.waitForAngular();
        browser.sleep(5000);
      //  console.log(dbQueryContract.numabo.result.rows[0][0]);

      dbQueryContract().then(function(criteria) {
      page2.searchInput.sendKeys(criteria, protractor.Key.ENTER);
    });


    next();
      });

this.When(/^i learn more$/, function(next) {
browser.sleep(5000);

       next();
  });


};
```

Comment: Try include some code we have somewhere to start?

Comment: thanx Ashley, i added the code

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't look right. Your module is exporting the result of invoking `new dbQueryContract();`. However, that function isn't really a constructor function. You're not setting any properties on `this` or adding any properties to the prototype. Also, you're not returning anything, which is probably why your getting undefined later.

The next problem is that you're chaining a `then` call, assuming that the driver uses promises - it doesn't (at least not yet). You'd need to have your function return a deferred which you'd need to resolve at the right time yourself. There's some discussion here about adding more robust JavaScript layer:
https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/pull/321

If we go that route I'd like to see all async methods return a promise by default which would make things easier...

Comment: thanx @Dan. Things got right with your advise and using Promises provided the best way to communicate with oracle database.

Comment: @IturnallSmile Just a heads up, those comments were from a while ago. The driver has supported promises for a while now. Here's a series that may help with async patterns (async/await being the latest) https://jsao.io/2017/06/how-to-get-use-and-close-a-db-connection-using-various-async-patterns/